# How to rename an object property values removing a specific object from the list

Tags: javascript, arrays, arrow-functions

I have a list of object

```
let table = [{id:4,val:"21321"},{id:5,val:"435345"},{id:6,val:"345345"}]
```

I want to rename the id value after removing an object from the list which has a specific id value(for example id:5)

I am using array filter method

```
table.filter((element,index)=>{
    if(element.id!==5){
        element.id=index
        return element 
    }else{
       index+1
    }
    return null
})
```

I am expecting a return value

```
[{id: 0,val: "21321"},{id: 1,val: "345345"}]
```

but i am getting this

```
[{id: 0, val: "21321"},{id: 2, val: "345345"}]
```

Note: I know i can use filter method to remove the specific object and than use map method to rename the id value but i want a solution where i have to use only one arrow function

Comment: The index in the filter call won't be equivalent to a subsequent map call because you don't know how many will be removed. It is better to be explicit (`filter().map()`) than do  inappropriate work within a method. Also `index` is passed by filter and won't retain your increment on the next iteration, you would need to declare a separate counter.

Comment: unclear what you think `index+1` is doing....

Comment: @epascarello in the else block if specific object is found increment index

Comment: It is not incrementing anything. `var x =1; x + 1; console.log(x);` Also it does nothing since the filter is not doing to do anything with it.

Comment: Do you want to reset id to 0 onward?

Comment: Why does it matter how many arrow functions are used? People should concentrate on making code work in a readable, maintainable way rather than adding silly restraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array#reduce` to update the indexes and remove elements with given id. For the matched id element, simply return the accumulator and for other, add new object with `val` and updated `id`.

```js
const data = [{ id: 4, val: "21321" }, { id: 5, val: "435345" }, { id: 6, val: "345345" }],
      result = data.reduce((res, {id, val}) => {
        if(id === 5) {
          return res;
        }
        res.push({id: res.length + 1, val});
        return res;
      }, []);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: your answer works for me can you please explain why you are using `res.push ` and empty array at the end.Thank you

Comment: The empty array at the end is the initial value of the array reduce, we are adding `res.push` to add updated id and val.

Answer (score 0):

This would do it:

```js
let table = [[{id:4,val:"21321"},{id:5,val:"435345"},{id:6,val:"345345"}]];

let res=table[0].reduce((a,c)=>{if(c.id!=5){
    c.id=a.length;
    a.push(c)
  }
  return a}, []);
  
console.log([res])
```

The only way to do it with "a single arrow function" is using `.reduce()`.

Here is an extremely shortened (one-liner) version of the same:

```
let res=table[0].reduce((a,c)=>(c.id!=5 && a.push(c.id=a.length,c),a),[]);
```

Actually, I was a bit premature with my remark about the "only possible solution". Here is a modified version of your approach using `.filter()` in combination with an IIFE ("immediately invoked functional expression"):

```js
table = [[{id:4,val:"21321"},{id:5,val:"435345"},{id:6,val:"345345"}]];

res= [ (i=>table[0].filter((element,index)=>{
    if(element.id!==5){
        element.id=i++
        return element 
    } }))(0) ];
    
console.log(res)
```

This IIFE is a simple way of introducing a persistent local variable `i` without polluting the global name space. But, stricly speaking, by doing that I have introduced a second "arrow function" ...

Comment: care to  explain why do you use `table[0]`

Comment: You have a nested array and the actual filtering should only be done on the inner array. If you want to maintain the nested array as a result you can pack `res` into an outer array again by surrounding the result with `[` and `]`:  `let res=[ table[0].reduce((a,c)=>(c.id!=5 && a.push(c.id=a.length,c),a),[]) ];`

Answer (score 0):

It probably is not the best practice to use filter and also alter the objects at the same time. But you would need to keep track of the count as you filter.

```js
let table = [[{id:4,val:"21321"},{id:5,val:"435345"},{id:6,val:"345345"}]]

const removeReorder = (data, id) => {
  var count = 0;
  return data.filter(obj => {
    if (obj.id !== id) {
      obj.id = count++;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  });
}

console.log(removeReorder(table[0], 5));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to achieve desired result by using `reduce` method:

```
const result = table.reduce((a, c) => {
    let nestedArray = [];
    c.forEach(el => {
        if (el.id != id)
            nestedArray.push({ id: nestedArray.length, val: el.val });
    });
    a.push(nestedArray);
    return a;
}, [])
```

An example:

```js
let table = [[{ id: 4, val: "21321" }, { id: 5, val: "435345" }, { id: 6, val: "345345" }]]
let id = 5;

const result = table.reduce((a, c) => {
    let nestedArray = [];
    c.forEach(el => {
        if (el.id != id)
            nestedArray.push({ id: nestedArray.length, val: el.val });
    });
    a.push(nestedArray);
    return a;
}, [])

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue in your code is `filter` method is not returning boolean value. Use the `filter` method to filter items and then use `map` to alter object.

```js
let table = [
  [
    { id: 4, val: "21321" },
    { id: 5, val: "435345" },
    { id: 6, val: "345345" },
  ],
];

const res = table[0]
  .filter(({ id }) => id !== 5)
  .map(({ val }, i) => ({ id: i, val }));
  
  
console.log(res)
```

Alternatively, using `forEach` with one iteration

```js
let table = [[{id:4,val:"21321"},{id:5,val:"435345"},{id:6,val:"345345"}]]

const res = []; 
let i = 0;
table[0].forEach(({id, val}) => id !== 5 && res.push({id: i++, val}));

console.log(res)
```

Comment: The first snippet is a bit misleading because the `id` argument to the `map` callback function has nothing to do with the `id` property. It is in fact the index of the item in the array on which `map` was called.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, Agree that it is not readable. Let me update that part to `map(({ val }, i) => ({ id: i, val }))` instead of `map(({ val }, id) => ({ id, val }))`. Thanks